# TensorFlow - Implementation of MCTS

Tags: tensorflow, montecarlo

I was wondering if there was a simple implementation of Monte Carlo Tree Search that has been done in TF. I couldn't find much, so I'm wondering if you guys know any.

Comment: Why would you specifically want to implement it using tensorflow? Doesn't really seem like a good fit to me.

Comment: @DennisSoemers What is the other option, PyTorch? I guess he just means the function approximator is in TensorFlow. I don't see why that's much worse than PyTorch.

Comment: @AnimeshSinha Well MCTS itself doesn't require anything like that, it's best implemented just in any plain programming language. Extending it with neural networks for policy and/or value functions... sure, for those specific parts it can make sense to use any of those frameworks.